# iOS Subclass inherits the parent class Xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I create a `superCell` with xib, and a subclass inherits the parent class, but the subclass has not xib, when I init subclass in `tableView(: UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` protocol, I cannot find xib' subviews, how to do?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    let firstCell = FirstTableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    firstCell.test.text = "subCell"
    return firstCell
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. [Edit] your question.

Comment: the first cell is inherits BaseTableViewCell, and BaseTableViewCell has xib file,but first cell has no

Comment: If the cell class isn't associated with a nib, how do you expect its outlets to have any values?

Comment: This is mean i can't use super xib file, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite your init function to load xib.